# How to filter data from CSV based on a the value of a colum

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

I have been trying to filter a data set of 100 entry points based on the value of the first column on the data set to create two separate variables with my data.

The values are filtered based on a zero or a 1 and then I want to store the rest of the data without the zero or one from first column. So far I have tried the following code but it doesn't seem to be working very well.

```
data1 = zeros(50,2)
data2 = zeros(50,2)

index1 = 0
index2 = 0

for i in 1:100    
    if data[i,1] < 0.5
        data1[index1] = data[i, 2:3]
        index+=1
    else 
        data2[index2] = data[i, 2:3]
        index2+=1
    end
end
```

The only thing I'm getting is this error, which I cannot understand

```
MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type DataFrames.DataFrameRow{DataFrames.DataFrame,DataFrames.SubIndex{DataFrames.Index,UnitRange{Int64},UnitRange{Int64}}} to an object of type Float64
Closest candidates are:
  convert(::Type{T}, !Matched::T) where T<:Number at number.jl:6
  convert(::Type{T}, !Matched::Number) where T<:Number at number.jl:7
  convert(::Type{T}, !Matched::Base.TwicePrecision) where T<:Number at twiceprecision.jl:250
  ...

Stacktrace:
 [1] setindex!(::Array{Float64,2}, ::DataFrames.DataFrameRow{DataFrames.DataFrame,DataFrames.SubIndex{DataFrames.Index,UnitRange{Int64},UnitRange{Int64}}}, ::Int64) at .\array.jl:825
 [2] top-level scope at .\In[47]:9
```

Comment: Could you please post what `data` is and how it is created in your code? It looks like it's a `DataFrame` from the error text, but it would be useful for us and others to know why the code is issuing the error and to help suggest an alternate solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make use of the `groupby` function from `DataFrames.jl`, which is the current default for `CSV.read`. In the future, you can use `CSV.File` and then collect that into a `DataFrame` or `Matrix` as you see fit.

```
# get groups based off the first column
groups = groupby(data, 1)
gcol = groupcol(groups)
# for each group, drop that column and collect into a DataFrame
# could easily collect into a Matrix, too!
data1, data2 = [DataFrame(g[!, Not(gcol)]) for g in groups]
```

EDIT: based on the comments from Bogumil I've updated the solution to use the current best practices!

Comment: A very nice answer. I have three small comments. `CSV.read` soon will be deprecated in CSV.jl so better use `CSV.File("your_file_name") |> DataFrame`. A second is that you do not have to remember what was a grouping column in a `GroupedDataFrame`, as now we provide `groupcols` and `valuecols` functions gives you this information. Finally I guess KeyboardHunter wanted to have a matrix in the output so instead of `DataFrame` in the last line one can just write `Matrix`.